# Added if statement to loop

Tags: loop

I'm trying to add a feature to my loop.php to use with a custom post type. However, I don't want it displayed on all posts, just the ones that are the custom post type (let's say its called "review").

Is there a way to say if post type = review then show this new section, otherwise hide?

I tried using

```
<?php if( get_post_type() == 'reviews' )
```

but I don't know how to phrase the else statement to just do nothing and continue on normally.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if ( have_posts() )
{
    while( have_posts() )
    {
        the_post();

        if ( 'reviews' === get_post_type( get_the_ID() )
        {
            echo 'I am a post of the post type &rdquo;reviews&ldquo;';

            // We're done here, continue to next post
            continue;
        }

        // Do other stuff
    }
}
```

#### EDIT

In case you're not sure if you got that post type available, use the following plugin to check (below your admin user interfaces footer) what custom post types you got available.

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: »kaiser« Get custom post type objects */
function wpsedebug_post_type_obj()
{
    if ( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    $pt = get_post_types(
         array(
             'public'   => true
            ,'_builtin' => false
         )
        ,'object'
    );
    return print '<pre>'.var_export( $pt, true ).'</pre>';
}
add_action( 'shutdown', 'wpsedebug_post_type_obj' );
```

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't display anything if I add that section in. Basically, as soon as I add an if statement to that part of the loop, it blanks out the page.

Comment: @BoShubinsky First: White screen means that there's an error and you haven't turned debugging on (see Codex for more info on how to debug in WP). Second: Take a look at the plugin I added to see what your post type really looks like/is named.

Answer (score 0):

try http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type use that to get your custom post type's value and to compare it

For instance:

```
<?php $myPostType = get_post_type( $post->ID ); 
 if($myPostType == 'Review'){
  //It's a review post type, whoo!
}
?>
```

Comment: When I try adding that to the loop, it just makes everything blank. It's not displaying any posts at all.

Comment: First try 
<?php echo get_post_type( $post->ID ); ?> and see which value it gives you

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to format it like this:

```
<?php if( get_post_type() == 'reviews' ) { ?>
// stuff inside if statement
<?php } ?>
```